# FusedLocationProviderClient doesn't retrieve any locations

Tags: java, android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I've been using the `FusedLocationProvider` api for a couple months now, but after an uncertain period, users report issues that stem from `FusedLocationProviderClient` not returning any locations in `onLocationResult`

[here](https://gist.github.com/TormundsMember/203b814d955b8094046edfb15bdba483) is a gist containing my locationhandler-class:

there are 3 assumptions that are proven to be correct

- it's not an issue of `permissions`, I have the same issue happening on my dev phone right now with all permissions granted.
- `GPS` is actived and set to GPS+WLAN mode.
- the call order was correct (disconnect() was not accidentally called after connect())

anyone, who can help me figure out what to do here?

Comment: Is your application registered at `Google Developer Console`

Comment: yes. Like I mentioned in the original question, we've used it for a couple months (actually, we've been using it since 2015)

Comment: Can you start google map and then try your application. I know its weird but try then if it is happening let me know I will give a solution.

Comment: @jiteshmohite that's what I usually told users to do. for some it worked, for others it didn't. but please post your solution